# How to identify missing dates from a time series data frame in R?

Tags: r

I had a data from 1980-2019. My study years were only 2017-2019. I subset the data using this command in R.

```
amt_789<-amtlich_1984_bis_2019_ana_d[amtlich_1984_bis_2019_ana_d$date >= "2017-01-01" &
                                     amtlich_1984_bis_2019_ana_d$date <= "2019-12-31",]
```

I want the subset data i.e. amt_789 to contain all days from 2017-2019 in a time series format. How can i check if **there are any missing dates in the amt_789 dataframe?**

I have checked and no other questions at stack platform answer my query. I would be glad if someone could help me with the command?

Answer (score 0):

Create a vector of all the dates you want, and see what's missing:

```
all_dates = seq(
  from = as.Date("2017-01-01"),
  to =  as.Date("2019-12-31"), 
  by = "day"
)

missing_dates = setdiff(all_dates, amt_789$date)
```

This assumes your `date` column is of class `Date`--if it isn't, you should convert it with `as.Date()`.